# Selecting a single value from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I select a single value through pandas library and assign it to a variable

```
import pandas as pd
returns = [0.0322, 0.3211, 0.0032]
symbols = ['A', 'B', 'C']

retdf = pd.DataFrame(returns, index=symbols, columns=['ret'])
retdf = retdf.ret.nlargest(1)
print(retdf)
```

Outputs

```
B    0.3211
```

How can I select `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'B' is an index, and you can refer it like below

```
print(retdf.index[0])
```